# RESTful API authorisation through client

Tags: api, rest, authorization

I'm currently writing an API to service my web APP. The APP is very client side oriented, having javascript handle routing and rendering etc. in the front end. To increase scalability the API is a completely separate resource. Having this setup I need to continually call the API from the front end to receive different types of data. 
Some of the services exposed by the API should be accessible only to the authorised user. So whenever users log in they are authorised server side and an `access_token` is created which should be passed through the `HTTP Auth.` header or as a query string for every request to a protected service. My concern is that to automate the authorised requests and avoid compromising the 'RESTfulness' of the API that i would need to store the `access_token` in the client side cache short term and as a cookie for returning users. 
 My question is, does it make sense to authorise in this fashion? I feel i don't need to use oauth at this development stage because the API only will be utilised by the APP itself. Moreover is it safe to store a 'long lived' token in the client cache or in a cookie to persist the logged in state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually most of the answers you are asking for are already in the solution you made, first let me say, yes, it's good to use a cookie for the user so that you don't have to do the authentication service again and again which reduces the load on your server, plus, since you got this far, I am sure you already know that you only have to do the authentication once and the server will recognize the user, in the way you did it, and the rest of the requests are mainly api requests, made for this authenticated user.
I prefer a short living cookie, or let me say, I prefer a very short living cookie for this matter, and this cookie should be made with a time out based on the client interaction with the server, this way you can make sure that when the user is off for a while, it's safe to clear the session from your server, and you can maintain a somehow secured environment.
I hope I answered your question, and please comment if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure I understand the concept: `you only have to do the authentication once and the server will recognize the user`.. I could naturally place a `$_SESSION` cookie (assuming PHP) server side to indicate a logged in state but that wouldn't be the RESTful way, I need clients to pass the full request object including the auth token on every request. Are you saying that the client side caches the `HTTP Auth` header and passes this automatically, after the initial request?

Comment: you are right, cookies are HTTP based therefore, not protocol independent and not very restful, but still manages to be a very good solution, and to be clear about it, the client should not work with the cookie or try to interpret it it just has to deliver it to the server, still, the best way to do it is query authentication (see this: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/12/principles-for-standardized-rest-authentication.html), but I ma not a very big fan of passing lots of data in the uri

Comment: Ok, good read! Seems I can accomplish my design securely with a SSL cert. Thank you for your time.

Comment: no problem, but just keep in mind the issues regarding the ssl cert regarding browser idiocy